# Turning bookmarklet into Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, bookmarklet

I'm trying to use `loadURI()` in a Google Chrome extension so that I can execute a bookmarklet when the toolbar button is pressed.

```
// in background.html
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  console.log('clicked!');
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "loadURI('http://www.google.com')"});
});
```

All I get is `'clicked!'` in the log and nothing else happens. No errors. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First, do you have permission for www.google.com? Second, what is `loadURI` to do? To navigate the current tab to google.com, use the `update()` function on the current tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loadURI()` is a Firefox specific function ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIWebNavigation#loadURI%28%29)).

The equivalent in Chrome is the `chrome.tabs.update()` function as documented [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-update).

The correct code would be:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "http://www.google.com"});
});
```

Remember to include the protocol eg. `http:` or `javascript:`